# Best practice for updating column specific triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers, optimistic-locking

Welcome Oracle pro's

In an Oracle 12 database (upgrade is already scheduled ;-)) we have a setup of different tables updating a common base table via "**after update**" triggers like following:

| Search_Flat |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | Field_A | Field_B | Field_C |

Now *table1* contains *n* columns where let's say 2 out of n are relevant for the Search_Flat table. As the update of table1 may only affect columns not relevant for Seach_Flat we want to add checks to the trigger. So our first approach is like following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_tbl_1_au_search
    AFTER UPDATE OF
        field_a,
        field_b
    ON schemauser.search_flat
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF :new.field_a <> :old.field_a THEN 
            UPDATE schemauser.search_flat SET field_a = :new.field_a WHERE id = :new.ID;
        END IF;
        IF :new.field_b <> :old.field_b THEN 
            UPDATE schemauser.search_flat SET field_b = :new.field_b WHERE id = :new.ID;
        END IF;
    END;
```

Alternatively we could also setup the trigger like following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_tbl_1_au_search
    AFTER UPDATE OF
        field_a,
        field_b
    ON schemauser.search_flat
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF :new.field_a <> :old.field_a OR :new.field_b <> :old.field_b THEN 
            UPDATE schemauser.search_flat 
            SET field_a = :new.field_a, 
                field_b = :new.field_b 
            WHERE id = :new.ID;
        END IF;
    END;
```

The question now is about the setup of the triggers themselves. Which approach is the better with respect to:

- locking time of search_flat rows
- overall performance of affected components (i.e., table_1, trigger and search_flat)

In production we are talking about 4 tables with 10 fields each considered in the triggers. And we have independent app servers accessing the shared database updating the 4 tables simultaneously. From time to time we detect the following error which is the reason we wan't to optimize the triggers:

> ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock

*Sidenote:* This setup has been chosen instead of a view or materialized view due to performance reasons as the base table is used in gui with the requirement to be instantly updated and the number of records of the 4 feeding tables are too high for updating materialized view on update.

I'm looking forward to the discussion and your thoughts.

Comment: The code has a trigger on SEARCH_UPDATE and an update on SEARCH_UPDATE; should one of those be TABLE1? Also, do the update statements just change one row at a time, or do they update multiple rows at once? A compound trigger could help improve performance if multiple rows are updated per statement.

Comment: _the number of records of the 4 feeding tables are too high for updating materialized view on update_ - if the rate of change is too high for a `fast refresh on commit` materialized view to be of use, a trigger based method like this is also likely to be too slow. Perhaps it would be better to describe the performance issues you have as there may be better alternatives

Comment: Hi @JonHeller , the trigger of table1 (tr_tbl_1_au_search) updates exactly one row in SEARCH_FLAT  (identified by ID) each time executed. So there will never be multiple rows affected at ones. But it may happen that affected row in table1 is updated simultaneously by different app servers, leading to the mentioned ORA timeout issue.

Comment: Hi @ChrisSaxon, were talking about millions of records multiplied by 4 incl. several joins each. The refresh on commit takes up to several minutes while the update triggers are approx. 98% within milliseconds. As long as only one application server is updating the base tables, performance is absolutely fine. We also discussed this problem with our DB pros and I do not think that the MV approach will be successful.

Comment: @Arno Sorry, I meant how is TABLE1 updated? If a SQL statement changes a hundred rows in TABLE1, a compound trigger could collect all of the necessary changes to SEARCH_FLAT and then apply them once at the end of the statement, instead of once per row.

Comment: @Arno - Does the process change x million rows, which then triggers 4x million updates? I'd be surprised triggers perform well in this case. As Jon asks, a full explanation of the overall process will help

Comment: You are on Oracle 12 database, you say.  Is that 12.1 or 12.2?  In 12.2, you can use a real-time materialized view to do this.  ("This" being "maintain a flattened table for searching without introducing any latency/staleness in the results").  Also, FWIW, the 2nd option you presented (one update instead of multiple updates) is better.  "Locking time" is irrelevant as the records will be locked until the transaction that invoked the trigger commits.  In your approach you also need to handle NULL comparisons better and watch out for deadlocks.  All told, you should abandon the triggers I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your post, you have 4 live tables (called "table1", "table2", etc.) that you want to search on, but querying from them is too slow, so you want to maintain a single, flattened table to search on instead and have triggers to keep that flattened table always up-to-date.
You want to know which of two trigger approaches is better.

I think the answer is "neither", since both are prone to deadlocks.  Imagine this scenario

User 1 -

```
UPDATE table1 
SET field_a = 500 
WHERE <condition effecting 200 distinct IDs>
```

User 2 at about the same time -

```
UPDATE table1 
SET field_b = 700 
WHERE <condition effecting 200 distinct IDs>
```

Triggers start processing.  You cannot control the order in which the rows are updated.  Maybe it goes like this:

User 1's trigger, time index 100 ->

```
UPDATE search_flat SET field_a = 500 WHERE id = 90;
```

User 2's trigger, time index 101 ->

```
UPDATE search_flat SET field_b = 700 WHERE id = 91;
```

User 1's trigger, time index 102 ->

```
UPDATE search_flat SET field_a = 500 WHERE id = 91;  (waits on user 2's session)
```

User 2's trigger, time index 103 ->

```
UPDATE search_flat SET field_b = 700 WHERE id = 90;  (deadlock error)
```

User 2's original update fails and rolls back.

You have multiple concurrent processes all updating the same set of rows in `search_flat` with no control over the processing order.  That is a recipe for deadlocks.

If you wanted to do this safely, you should consider neither of the `FOR EACH ROW` trigger approaches you outlines.  Rather, make a compound trigger to do this.

Here's some sample code to illustrate the idea.  Be sure to read the comments.

```
-- Aside: consider setting this at the system level if on 12.2 or later
--   alter system set temp_undo_enabled=false;

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table1_updates_gtt (
  id          NUMBER,
  field_a     VARCHAR2(80),
  field_b     VARCHAR2(80)
) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table2_updates_gtt (
  id          NUMBER,
  field_a     VARCHAR2(80)
) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

-- .. so on for table3 and 4.

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_search_maint_trg
  FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON table1  -- with similar compound triggers for table2, 3, 4.
    COMPOUND TRIGGER

  AFTER EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    -- Update the table-1 specific GTT with the changes.
    CASE WHEN INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
      -- Assumes ID is immutable primary key
      INSERT INTO table1_updates_gtt (id, field_a) VALUES (:new.id, :new.field_a);
         WHEN DELETING THEN
      INSERT INTO table1_updates_gtt (id, field_a) VALUES (:old.id, null);  -- or figure out what you want to do about deletes.
    END CASE;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    -- Write the data from the GTT to the search_flat table.
    -- NOTE: The ORDER BY in the next line is what saves us from deadlocks.
    FOR r IN ( SELECT id, field_a, field_b FROM table1_updates_gtt ORDER BY id ) LOOP
      -- TODO: replace with BULK processing for better performance, if DMLs can affect a lot of rows
      UPDATE search_flat sf
      SET    sf.field_a = r.field_a,
             sf.field_b = r.field_b
      WHERE  sf.id = r.id
      AND    ( sf.field_a <> r.field_a 
               OR (sf.field_a IS NULL AND r.field_a IS NOT NULL) 
               OR (sf.field_a IS NOT NULL AND r.field_a IS NULL)
               OR sf.field_b <> r.field_b 
               OR (sf.field_b IS NULL AND r.field_b IS NOT NULL) 
               OR (sf.field_b IS NOT NULL AND r.field_b IS NULL)
             );
    END LOOP;             
          
  END AFTER STATEMENT;

END table1_search_maint_trg;
```

Also, as numerous commenters have pointed out, it's probably better to use a materialized view for this.  If you are on 12.2 or later, real-time materialized views (aka "ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION") offer a lot of promise for this sort of thing.  No `COMMIT` overhead to your application and real-time search results.  It's just that search time degrades slightly if there are a lot of recent updates to the underlying tables.

Comment: Hi @Matthew, thanks for your explanation which sounds reasonable for me and delivers at least the reason for the deadlock. The updates on single base tables are no mass updates and only single rows are going to be updated per user action. Nevertheless it seems to be sufficient for the deadlocks ;-)

Comment: You asked in comment above for the version which is currently Oracle 12.2 but migration to 19.x is scheduled for Q4. So the approach with the compound triggers seems to be worth a  try and I didn't know them yet. As long term solution I'll also check the possibilities with MV again, presumably after the migration. I'll keep you posted here ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, if your application does single-row updates to the base tables and your are getting deadlocks, the compound trigger will not solve your problem (each `AFTER STATEMENT` run will just process one row).  You would either need to modify the underlying application to update all base tables in a consistent order (e.g., by `ID`) or forget about using triggers.

Comment: One thing else -- designers often place too much emphasis (imo) on "real time" results.  But unless (A) the application is such where the same users are updating the data and then running the search, expecting their updates to be shown in the results or (B) the application is making promises that need real-time data to be accurate (e.g., a ticketing application), "near real-time" is usually just as good and opens up a LOT more design options.

Comment: The application matches your option A) where the "Service Desk" user updates an incident and instantly updates result view afterwards (i.e. search) to verify subsequent processes. Thus kind of "real time" updates is one of their requirement. Former solution handled the synch between normalized tables and search inside the application resulting in some data mismatches. So we want the database taking care of synchronized data as its part of db's sovereignty.